# If $|f|$ is constant, so is $f$ for $f$ analytic on a domain $D$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading through a development of the maximum modulous principle, but I am stuck verifying a remark:

$$\text{"it is enough to show that $|f|$ is constant, from which we may conclude that $f$ is.''}$$

So I am trying to prove it as a lemma:

Let $f$ be analytic on a domain $D$.  If $|f|$ is constant then so is $f$.

I tried using the fact that $|f|$ constant implies $|f|$ is analytic.

From here this means that $Re(|f(x,y)|)$ is harmonic.

I wrote out the consequence to this using Laplace's Equation, hoping to force the partial derivatives of $f$ to vanish, but it didn't seem to go anywhere.

Any suggestions?

Comment: damien's answer is correct. also note that more generally, every holomorphic function is either open (ie the image of any open set is open) or constant.

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki: Well, yes, as long as your domain is connected, which I'm sure you meant to say.

Comment: @J.Loreaux : yes. for some people (me among them!) "domain" means connected open set

Comment: In this problem, were you able to use the fact that if $f' \equiv 0$ on $D$, then $f$ is constant on $D$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $f=u+iv$ be analytic on some domain $D$. Suppose the modulus is constant, so $u^2+v^2$ is constant. It follows that 
$$
u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+v\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=0
$$
and
$$
u\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+v\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=-u\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}+v\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=0.
$$
These imply that $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}=0=\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}$ save when $u^2+v^2$ vanishes. This follows by considering the matrix equation
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
u & v\\
v & -u\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\end{array}\right)=0
$$
However, if $u^2+v^2=0$ at some point, then it is constantly $0$ in which case $f(z)$ vanishes identically.

Comment: This is great.  Thanks!

Comment: @Kyle Happy to help.