# Show with maximum principle: $|f|$ constant, f analytic, then $f$ constant in open domain $D$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f=u+iv$ be analytic in an open domain $D$.
If $|f|$ is constant in $D$, show, with the maximum principle, that $f$ is constant on $D$.

The proof through Cauchy-Riemann is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/294877/14108).
There it is mentioned that the result can be shown with the maximum principle.
I don't see how the proof goes.
From the maximum principle, I can write
$$
k = u^2+v^2 \le \left| f\left( z \right) \right|,
$$
for $z$ in the boundary, and $k=|f|$ on $D$.

Comment: It seems to follow directly from the theorem presented on wikipedia

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle

Note the $\geq$ sign

Comment: @user45150 Very true, thanks.

Comment: You can see this more directly with the open (or local) mapping theorem. Assuming $f$ is nonconstant, it takes a neighborhood to a neighborhood. But $|w| = C$ for a constant $C$ is a circle and isn't open in $\mathbb{C}$, hence $f$ must be constant. Of course, the maximum modulus principle follows as well from this line of reasoning.